# Можно ли переносить слово "жизнь"?

Tags: орфография

Можно ли переносить слово "жизнь"?

Answer (score 1):

Не "не нужно", а нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

По правилу здесь 1 гласный звук, 1 слог. Не нужно переносить.